# how to make a message model in Django where you can choose more than one person as the recipient

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

So, I'm trying to make a messaging model(between users) in Django admin where the sender can choose more than one recipient for the message.
Models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=50, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,editable=False)
    recipient = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subject)
```

admin.py:

```
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.sender = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        sender_query = qs.filter(sender=request.user)
        recipient_query = qs.filter(recipient=request.user)
        return sender_query | recipient_query
```

My current approach is the code above using a `ManyToManyField`. But this has created two bugs:

1. The sender will see the same message more than once if more than one recipient are chosen, for example if the sender chooses three recipients, he will have three of the same message in his queryset
2. The sender will not be able to open the message he has sent(if more than one recipient are chosen) because this error will get raised:`get() returned more than one Message -- it returned 2!`. of course the "2" can be any other number

The thing I can't figure out Is that these bugs won't produce if the sender is superuser(And I assume that means there is a problem with my `get_queryset` code)

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: We've got an app that does email sending and we split the models up into `MessageTemplate` which contains the content of the message, then `Message` which has sender, recipient and a FK to the `MessageTemplate`. So a single `Message` instance represents an email sent. I think this would help you achieve what you want.

Comment: There's something we'renot seeing here. The number of records in a M2M field will not determine how many records that `get_queryset` model returns. The maximum number of times a person should see the same message is 2 - and that's only if they've put themselves down as a recipient when they're also the sender!

Comment: @michjnich I just edited the question and that's almost all of my admin.py and models.py about messages, and still can't figure out why that happens, when I try it, and mark 4 people as recipients, the sender will see 4 of the same message(except if he is superuser)

Comment: I suspect it's the `recipient_query` that is throwing you off now I think about it. You need to filter on the values on the relationship, since an m2m field works using a "through" table that DJango hides from you. Does this question help you at all? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428816/filtering-django-queryset-by-a-value-of-the-through-table-of-a-m2m-relationship

Answer (score 1):

- You just need to add related_name in each field,
  the related_name must be different or you can use related_name='+'
- from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/)
  the related_name is the name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one. It’s also the default value for related_query_name
- in your case **you set the same name** for **different relations**